# Why isn't jQuery Post sending any data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use Instafeed to show my Instagram feed on my website. However, I do not want to run it everytime someone accesses my website, so I'm trying to write the response to a file. For that I am using the following code

```
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: 'xxx',
    accessToken: 'xxx',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    limit: '12',
    template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" title="{{caption}}"/></a>',
    link: 'true',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);

        $.post('saveInstagram.php', {list: response.data}, function(o) {
               console.log(o);
        }, 'json');

    }
});
userFeed.run();
```

saveInstagram.php (very basic, just to test)

```
$list = $_POST['list'];

$myfile = fopen("instagramFeed.html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $list);
fclose($myfile);
```

The console log shows the correct data which should get sent to saveInstagram.php. The response isn't being sent however. I tried changing the value manually to {list: 'test'} in order to check the save-script, and that works, 'test' is being written to the file. So I don't seem to understand why response.data isn't being sent by the script, but does show up in the console.log. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are the contents of `response.data` and show `saveInstagram.php`

Comment: @Musa added the basic saveInstagram.php code. response.data is a large multidimensional array. Not sure how to post it here

Comment: Just post the first couple entries, so we understand what it looks like.

Comment: So fwrite takes a string, but you're passing it an array...

Comment: @Musa Indeed, I was just trying something else just to check, and changing the save script to $list = $_POST['list'][0]['caption']['created_time']; made it work. So it looks like I should first process the data. I didn't realize that, since I just wanted to test first whether the data got send. Thanks for the help!